# Troubles with color in modal controller rendering

Tags: ios, metal

I have metal objects in main and modal view controllers.

**main** *UIViewController*:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   … 
   _mtlLayer = [CAMetalLayer new];   
   _mtlLayer.frame = self.view.layer.frame;
   [self.view.layer addSublayer:_mtlLayer];

   /* set the pointer to renderer */
   …
   /* method "draw" run "drawPrimitive" don't use "CADisplayLink" */
   [_renderer draw];
}
```

modal view controller call method of **main**:

```
- (void)showModalController 
{
   DGAModalViewController *modal = [[DGAModalViewController alloc] init];  
   modal.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverFullScreen;    
   [self presentViewController:modal animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

The rendering visualization will output in the **_imageView** (*UIImageView*), which is added to **the modal controller** when it is initialized.
The **_imageView** is initialized with a frame, but does not yet have an image.
The image will be added later in the method *viewDidLayoutSubviews*, where **_imageView** gets *CGImage* from **renderer**.

Rendering is done in both the **main** and **modal** controllers using the same pipeline settings and the same command queue. Also, some data buffers are shared for rendering by both controllers.
Rendering occurs with different textures.
The **main** controller uses a triple buffering for animation.

If an animation was run in the *presentingViewController* before calling the modal controller, the **_imageView** is displayed well. Otherwise, the **_imageView** will fill all outlines with black.

If **_imageView** is replaced with *CAMetalLayer*, then it is enough to call [*self.presentingViewController draw*] (no *CADisplayLink* and *RunLoop*) after or before calling the modal controller so that its image is colored. Otherwise, it is also filled with black.

What prevents the image from being displayed correctly right away?

**P.S.** This problem is somehow affected by triple buffering.
The **draw** method of renderer is used for both creating a still image  and for animation on CAMetalLayer of presentingController. This method *uses triple buffering*.
The **drawImage** method of renderer that creates a CGImage in a modal window *does not use triple buffering*. If I call the draw method twice on the CAMetalLayer main controller before calling the modal controller, then rendering in the modal happens perfectly.

Filling the entire volume of triple buffers with data and assigning any index at the first render call from main controller is not a solution to the problem.